# Ленивая загрузка элементов

Tags: javascript, lazyloading

Интересует механизм загрузки элементов, представляющих из себя блоки с данными: `title`, `content`, ...

Бытовая ситуация: создаем определенное количество `todo-item` и каждый записываем в БД. Но как после перезагрузки страницы загрузить N-oe количество элементов и во время скролла догружать еще столько же или сколько останется ?.

**P.S**: У каждого `todo-item` имеется intersectionObserver, который отправляет fetch запрос, в теле которого `ID`, установленный объекте, и получает данные.

Comment: в чем конкретно проблема то? событие скролла отбрабатывайте да запрашивайте аяксом новые данные.

Comment: @teran Что не понятного? Я конкретно написал: "Как загрузить N-ое кол-во элементов". Меня интересует каким способом можно взять это число

Comment: Если используете sql, то можете передавать с клиента на сервер кол-во уже загруженных todo, и в select установить offset и задать limit.

Comment: @СергейБараненков Спасибо, хотя бы к идеи подтолкнул, но, к сожалению, использую монго

Comment: @fureinzz это примерно как спросить "как сварить суп", при этом не уточняя какой именно суп вы собираетесь варить, и какие ингредиенты у вас имеются. потом еще оказывается что плиты у вас нет, а есть только керосинка, правда за керосином надо сходить в магазин. но поскольку все на изоляции то выход из дома запрещен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В монго попробуйте `db.collection.find().skip(n).limit(m)`